# How to clear certain cells on opening a spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I am trying to get my Google Sheet to clear certain cells on opening it.  I've never added Apps Script to any sheet, so step by sp instructions will be greatly appreciated.

I'm getting an error when trying to deploy the script below.

```
function onOpen() { 
  function clearRange() {
      // replace 'Sheet2' with your actual sheet name
      // replace '1AsVArsUf5DaIXqzyPEokCRkPVglxSPW4NgWg_PVtLhA/edit#gid=1395849459' with your actual sheet ID

      var sheetActive = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1AsVArsUf5DaIXqzyPEokCRkPVglxSPW4NgWg_PVtLhA/edit#gid=1395849459").getSheetByName("Sheet2");
      sheetActive.getRange('G83,G143,E143,G210,G221').clearContent();

    }

}
```

Comment: whats the errors?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please start by reading https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets, https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers and https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Clear Ranges:

```
function onOpen() {
  clearRange()
}
function clearRange() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1AsVArsUf5DaIXqzyPEokCRkPVglxSPW4NgWg_PVtLhA/edit#gid=1395849459");
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  const rgl = sh.getRangeList(['G83','G143','E143','G210','G221']).getRanges().forEach(r => r.clearContent())
}
```

You probably need an installable trigger because you are using openById()

- [Sheet.getRangeList](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRangeList(String))